# Want to show output as tabular form of bash scripts

Tags: bash, tabular

**I want to add below data under column name as**

1. Number
2. Name
3. Result

Here are the script

```sh
echo -e "01. testing 123 \\t PASS"
echo -e "02. testing 123 \\t PASS"
echo -e "03. testing 123 \\t PASS"
echo -e "04. testing 123 \\t PASS"
echo -e "05. testing 123 \\t PASS"
```

I have tried every command but didn't get result

Comment: Don't use `echo` use `printf`, e.g. `printf "%02d. %-12s %s\n" "1" "testing 123" "PASS"`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `echo` use `printf`, e.g.

```sh
printf "%02d. %-12s %s\n" "1" "testing 123" "PASS"
```

You can substitute variables for `"1"`, `"testing 123"` and `"PASS"`. The number will be 0-padded and displayed as 2-digits up to `100` and then 3-digits are required. You can change the field-width modifier in `"%02d"` to `"%03d"` to handle alignment of 3 digits (4 for 4-digits, etc...)

The `"testing 123"` text will always be displayed left-justified (`'-'`) and in a field 12-characters wide (adjust as needed). With the first two-fields displayed, you can simply output the last one and it will take whatever space it takes.

You can substitute `'\t'` for the space separator between the format-specifiers in the `printf` statement if you want the columns tab-separated, e.g.

```sh
printf "%02d.\t%-12s\t%s\n" "1" "testing 123" "PASS"
```

See [man 3 printf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) for the complete use of `printf`.